# Show that $p(A) = \begin{bmatrix} p(A_{11})&(Mess)\\ 0&p(A_{22})\\ \end{bmatrix}$ for any polynomial $p(x)$. (See problem for full question.)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Important Note: This is a homework problem.

The full question is as follows:

If

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}\\ 0&A_{22}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

where $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are square, show that

$$p(A) = \begin{bmatrix} p(A_{11})&(Mess)\\ 0&p(A_{22})\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

for any polynomial p(x).

Honestly I'm at a complete loss as to how I should even begin showing this is true. I know how to apply a polynomial to a matrix but that's about it. The only thing that comes to mind is that it might have something to do with diagonalization.

Thank you for any help in getting started with this.

Comment: Hint :- its upper triangle matrix , so  any multply or addition or any possible operation on diagonals , its only need to know the element in diagonal itself else wont effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try computing powers of $A$ and see if you notice a pattern:

$A^2 = A \cdot A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}\\ 0&A_{22}\\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}\\ 0&A_{22}\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}^2&A_{11}A_{12}+A_{12}A_{22}\\ 0&A_{22}^2\\ \end{bmatrix}$

$A^3 = A \cdot A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}\\ 0&A_{22}\\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}^2&A_{11}A_{12}+A_{12}A_{22}\\ 0&A_{22}^2\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}^3&\text{Mess}_3\\ 0&A_{22}^3\\ \end{bmatrix}$

$A^4 = A \cdot A^3 = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}\\ 0&A_{22}\\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}^3&\text{Mess}_3\\ 0&A_{22}^3\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}^4&\text{Mess}_4\\ 0&A_{22}^4\\ \end{bmatrix}$

...

Now, try to prove some sort of pattern for $A^n$ by induction.

Finally, compute $p(A) = p_0I+p_1A+p_2A^2+\cdots+p_nA^n$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense and I think I got it. Once again, the answer is much simpler than I originally thought.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show the claim first for $p(x) = x^2$, then for $p(x) = x^n$, then for $p(x) = ax^n$, then in general.